# Creating Proportional Symbols with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, web-mapping, markers, ajax

[image]

[image]

After converting the data in this table to geojson, I want to present it on the map by sizing it according to the "y_2021" values, but I get many errors like in the picture. Can you help me find out why? I think there is a problem with my data types

```
    var map;
    var minValue;


    //create the map

    function calculateMinValue(data){
        //create empty array to store all data values
        var allValues = [];
        //loop through each city
        for(var district of data.features){
            //loop through each year
            for(var year = 2017; year <= 2021; year+=5){
                  //get population for current year
                  var value = district.properties["y_"+ String(year)];
                  //add value to array
                  allValues.push(value);
            }
        }
        //get minimum value of our array
        var minValue = Math.min(...allValues)
    
        return minValue;
    }

//calculate the radius of each proportional symbol

    function calcPropRadius(attValue) {
       
        var minRadius = 1;
        //Flannery Apperance Compensation formula
        var radius = 1.0083 * Math.pow(attValue/minValue,0.5715) * minRadius
    
        return radius;
    };

        function createPropSymbols(data){
         
            var attribute = "y_2021";
        
            var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
                fillColor: "#ff7800",
                color: "#fff",
                weight: 1,
                opacity: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0.8,
                radius: 8
            };
    
    L.geoJson(data, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                //Step 5: For each feature, determine its value for the selected attribute
                var attValue = Number(feature.properties[attribute]);
    
                //Step 6: Give each feature's circle marker a radius based on its attribute value
                geojsonMarkerOptions.radius = calcPropRadius(attValue);
    
                //create circle markers
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
            }
        }).addTo(map);
    };

    function getData(map){
        
        fetch("data/tree_cover_loss.geojson")
            .then(function(response){
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(json){
                //calculate minimum data value
                minValue = calculateMinValue(json);
                //call function to create proportional symbols
                createPropSymbols(json);
            })
    };

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',createMap)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be consequence of using the same global object `geojsonMarkerOptions` for creating all markers, but changing it's `radius` property in the process. This might have side effect on already created markers.

Instead of changing `radius` property you can set marker radius with `.setRadius` method. This could look something like this:

```
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
  fillColor: "#ff7800",
  color: "#fff",
  weight: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  fillOpacity: 0.8
};

L.geoJson(data, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    var attValue = Number(feature.properties[attribute]);
    var marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
    marker.setRadius(attValue);
    return marker;
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: That worked, thank you.